# Задать свойства нескольким элементам

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли сделать так, что бы вместо того что бы писать одинаковые свойства для двух элементов раздельно, объединить эти свойства?
Пробовал так, но это не работает:

```
Panel panZZZ, panYYY = new Panel
{
  AutoSize = true
};
```

Comment: `foreach (var panel in new Panel[]{panel1, panel2}) panel.AutoSize = true;`

Comment: @tym32167.  Благодарю, помог! Можешь добавить как ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте массив и работайте с ним

```
foreach (var panel in new Panel[]{panel1, panel2}) 
{
    panel.AutoSize = true;
}
```

Как альтернативный вариант, можно сделать себе метод для создания панелей

```
private Panel CreatePanel()
{
    return new Panel
    {
        AutoSize = true
    };
}
```

Получится так

```
Panel panel1 = CreatePanel();
Panel panel2 = CreatePanel();
```

Способ полезный для того, чтобы не дублировать код. [Пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1195973/373567).

Comment: Заберите пожалуйста к себе в ответ мой вариант. Не люблю красть галочки и непринятые ответы :) А кому-то может пригодиться.

Comment: @aepot теперь я должен вам пол галки :)